# Appium installation with npm failing on macOS

Tags: macos, npm, appium, npm-install

When running `npm install -g appium`, installation fails with the following log:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /usr/local/Cellar/node/15.1.0/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.1.0/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lgn/.npm/_logs/2020-11-09T08_33_15_328Z-debug.log
```